# unexpected behaviour of "unfiltered" search in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-7, cts-search

Unfiltered search is giving wrong results.

please find the below xml samples and problem.

Sample:

```
<root>
    <id1>11</id1>
    <elem1>ee1</elem1>
    <ele2>ee2</ele2>
    <entry>
        <volume>10</volume>
        <issue>10</issue>
        <elemEntry>eleme</elemEntry>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <volume>20</volume>
        <issue>20</issue>
        <elemEntry>eleme</elemEntry>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <volume>20</volume>
        <issue>10</issue>
        <elemEntry>eleme</elemEntry>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <volume>10</volume>
        <issue>20</issue>
        <elemEntry>eleme</elemEntry>
    </entry>
</root>
```

I have to get the entry nodes with value combination of `<volume> & <issue>` both should present under `<entry>` node (like : volume-10 & issue-10, volume-10 & issue-20)

As in the above example, I need the entire entry node as `<volume> (10), <issue> (10)`.

It should not return me the other entry nodes as other entry nodes doesn't have the required `volume` (value 10), `issue` (value 10) combination.

Please find below the `cts:search` which I am doing.

```
cts:search(
    doc("/sample.xml")//entry,
    cts:and-query((
        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("volume"), "10", ("case-insensitive","unstemmed")),
        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("issue"), "10", ("case-insensitive","unstemmed"))
    )),
    "unfiltered"
)
```

Assume sample xml is stored in the DB with `/sample.xml` uri

Above query is returning me the other entries (`<entry>`) also.

If I will perform **"filtered"** search, above query is returning me the correct results.

**Please tell me, why it is happening and what would be the solution**.

If there is any other good way to get the entry nodes having combination of `volume and issue` please let me know.

Comment: Try enabling the index `element value positions`.

Comment: @wst It's already set to "true" but still facing the problem.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but you could also try `word positions` and `element word positions`. Otherwise, I think that would exhaust what can be resolved from indexes and therefore unfiltered queries, and you would need to remodel the data.

Comment: why do you have "case-insensitive" and "unstemmed" to match numbers?  have you tried removing those?  Also, have you looked at cts:element-query?  I'd expect to see that around your cts:and-query if you want both matches to only match within one element.  I don't know off-hand, however, whether you can do that type of query unfiltered.

Comment: @SamMefford Just to explain the problem I am using number values. But in actual volume, issue nodes will contain string type. 

I have tried with cts:element-query also... but no gain..

Comment: @wst `word positions` and `element word positions` are also set to true..

Comment: Then you will probably need to change the structure of your XML to facilitate the type of unfiltered query you want, as suggested by @mholstege.

Comment: Dixit, could you share your query using cts:element-query?

Answer (score 4):

You should also consider changing your data model. MarkLogic is best used when 1 document = 1 row. You will have more efficient queries and can use smaller indexes if you follow that pattern. The indexes are all oriented around facts-in-document and to get subdocument restrictions like this you need to use positions, which can get expensive, or filtered searches, which are even more expensive.